# how to I see the line number of source code that's causing a segmentation fault in my c program

Tags: debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

I know I can see the line number by running the program and call a "where" or "bt" to see the current halted line. but this line number is represented in hex form, which means it's a machines based line number. How can I go from this number to get the line number in my source code. For example the current line number looks like this;

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000404a9d in ex ()
#1  0x0000000000404b63 in ex ()
#2  0x0000000000404369 in ex_wrap ()
#3  0x0000000000403259 in yyparse ()
#4  0x00000000004042ff in main ()
```

I want sth like

```
line 55 in the file "foo.c":blablalba
```

Comment: Daniel, you need to build you program with debugging symbols. If you build with gcc, them read about its option `-g` and rebuild your program with it. As soon as your executable has debugging symbols gdb will load them. This is where you can read about `-g` http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options: Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but this line number is represented in hex form, which means it's a machines based line number.

There is no such thing as "machine based line number". A number is a number, whether expressed in hex, decimal, or octal.

What you are seeing as hex numbers are not line numbers at all; these are values of program counters (aka machine addresses).

The reason that you are not seeing file / line info is that you've compiled or linked your code without `-g` flag, or you (likely accidentally) stripped debug info (a "stray" `-s` on the link line is a frequent cause).